# Spring boot Loading multiple properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, properties-file

I have a application.properties which specifies the name of properties files to be loaded into the application.

application.properties

```
sources=a_source,b_source,c_source
```

The a_source, b_source and c_source has the same variables.

a_source.properties

```
location = locationb
```

b_source.properties

```
location = locationb
```

c_source.properties

```
location=locationc
```

So if i add a name of properties file into application.properties say d_source, then d_source.properties should be automatically loaded by the application. So that my application can work the data from the 4 properties files. Is this possible in spring boot?

Comment: Why would you require multiple properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to treat the multiple application properties as multiple java property resources, then you are on a wrong foot. You can't and you shouldn't. Each application defines one property/yaml file per environment/profile.

However, if you want treat the application.properties or yaml as environment/profile basis you can do as follows:

Eg.,

***application-integration_test.yaml:***

```
spring.profiles: integration_test
spring.profiles.include:
  - unit_test
  - mock_test
```

In the above one, what you are saying is whenever you have an active profile of "integration_test", also include config from "unit_test" and "mock_test" profiles.

> But please note that if any same or duplicate properties or config keys
>   defined in included profiles, the properties values are overridden and
>   replaced by the next mentioned profile. In this case if you had same
>   property keys with different values in all 3 profiles, the mock_test
>   profiles' value is used as final value.

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using Profiles. Check this out:
[Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)
[Profile Specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties)

Comment: but at a time only one profile can active for the application, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also using this solution:

**application-unit_test.properties**

```
# content of file
```

**application-mock_test.properties**

```
# content of file
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profile.active = default
spring.profiles.include = unit_test, mock_test
```